# how to apply a material design to file input tag?

Tags: web, material-design, material-design-lite, web-frontend

I'm designing a website using google's material design lite, in my home page I have a file input tag

```
    <input type="file">
```

the problem is that I can't find the appropriate mdl classes for styling this element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example to give you an idea:

```
<style>#file { display: none; }</style>
<label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--file">
  <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i><input type="file" id="file">
</label>
```

It uses a MDL icon as a button for the user to click to pull up the file input prompt.